# Gradle: how to copy file but keep the same build invocation?

Tags: configuration, gradle, file-copying

Currently my Gradle build produces a fat JAR (via [ShadowJar Plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)) under `build/distributions` via the following build invocation:

```
gradle clean build shadowJar
```

I now need that *same exact* build invocation to copy `src/main/resources/myconfig.json` to `build/distributions` as well. I followed the [Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) and added the following to my build:

```
task copyConfig(type: Copy) {
    into 'build/distributions'
    from('src/main/resources') {
        include '**/*.json'
    }
}
```

However running `gradle clean build shadowJar` doesn't produce a `build/distributions/myconfig.json` as expected. **What can I do to keep the build invocation exactly the same, but to invoke the `copyConfig` task (also, I'm not even 100% sure that task is error-free)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a task, but you never execute it. In order for this task to be invoked when executing build or shadowJar, one of these tasks needs to depend on the task you created:

```
build.dependsOn copyConfig
```

or

```
shadowJar.dependsOn copyConfig
```

Comment: Awesome, makes sense that @JB Nizet (+1) - I'm still **very** new to Gradle.